# How can I get the predict future following value using Tensorflow LSTM?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, lstm, predict

Thank you for reading. I'm not good at English.

I am wondering how to predict and get future time series data after model training. I would like to get the values after N steps.

So, I used the time series in the Tensorflow tutorial to practice predicting the model.

```
a = y_val[-look_back:] 
for i in range(N-step prediction): #predict a new value n times.
    tmp = model.predict(a.reshape(-1, look_back, num_feature)) #predicted value     
    a = a[1:] #remove first     
    a = np.append(a, tmp) #insert predicted value
```

The results are predicted by linear graphs from nonlinear graphs as shown below.

[image: 1]

How can I get the actual, right solution? or Is Tessorflow impossible to predict multiple steps?

[full source](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/96e0ba8d8c251046e89eae4bc5d40510)  (After the 25th line is my code.)

[epoch=100](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/3c530649934af39a6c6e9884a8eb14fd)

Comment: Welcome to DS StackExchange. Please update your question provoding more information about the data you are working with, the structure of your dataset, and you model's architecture. As of now, it's very hard to tell where the problem is.

Comment: Of course, as you may know, this dataset is the dataset and model architecture provided by the Tensorflow tutorial. As of now, Please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series